# plm() with maximum likelihood estimation?

Tags: instrumentation, panel-data, plm, mle

I would like to estimate a panel data model with instrumental variables using maximum likelihood estimation. Is this possible in R?

With the `plm()` function from the `plm` package, I can instrument for endogenous variables in a panel data model with OLS, but --- as far as I know --- not MLE. By contrast, if I use the `treatReg()` function from the `sampleSelection` package, I can fit a model with IVs using MLE, but it is not built to work with panel data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, `plm` does not employ MLE.